# A doubt in a Wikipedia article discussing Bertrand's Theorem in Central force motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

*Wikipedia* on  Bertrand's theorem, when discussing the deviations from a circular orbit says:

> ...The next step is to consider the equation for $u$ under small perturbations ${\displaystyle \eta \equiv u-u_{0}}$ from perfectly circular orbits.

(Here $u$ is related to the radial distance as $u=1/r$ and $u_0$ corresponds to the radius of a circular orbit  ) ...

The deviations are as

> The solutions are
> ${\displaystyle \eta (\theta )=h_{1}\cos(\beta \theta ),}$

> For the orbits to be closed, $β$ must be a rational number. What's more, **it must be the same rational number for all radii**, since β cannot change continuously; the rational numbers are totally disconnected from one another

Why does $\beta$ have to be the **same** rational number for all radii at which a circular orbit is possible?

I understand why it should be rational, but why the same number for all radii?

Link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable $\beta$ must vary continuously with the radius because it is defined in terms of another function $J$ that varies continuously with the radius. Now, suppose there are radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $\beta(r_1)=3$ and $\beta(r_2)=3.2$. Because $\beta$ is continuous, there must be a radius $r_3$ between $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $\beta(r_3)=\pi$. This cannot happen because $\beta$ must be rational, and there is no such thing as varying continuously over the rational numbers. So, $\beta$ cannot vary and must be constant.

Comment: But β is defined only at specific radii where we've a circular orbit. So β isn't a continuous function to begin with as is defined  in the article : ${\displaystyle \beta ^{2}\equiv 1-J'(u_{0})}$

Comment: @Kashmiri Circular orbits can occur at any radius, so $u_0$ is a continuous variable. If you can calculate different $\beta$s at different radii, then $\beta$ must vary continuously.

Comment: So basically we are interested in such a force that produces closed orbits for small perturbations for all  radii where circular orbits are possible  and for that β has to be constant rational?

Comment: @Kashmiri Right. For central forces that only depend on distance, it is always possible to create a circular orbit at any radius by correctly setting the initial velocity.

Comment: Thank you so much. :)